# jQuery Preloader with min-time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Heyo,

I was wondering if there would be a way to set a `min-time` to an `onload function` so that the `div` is shown `min 2sec`. Basicly the same as with `min-width` or `min-height`. If the site is taking longer than `2sec` to load, the `div` will still be shown untill the site is fully loaded but when the site takes less than `2sec` to load the `div` will still be displayed for a minimum of `2sec`.

Here is my current code:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('.preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I take it you want a function to be run when either: the page loads or after 2 seconds, whatever comes later.

First, define a function to be called:

```
function load_func() {
    $('.preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
}
```

Then, let's define a way to call the function in either situation:

```
var pageLoaded = false;
var timeoutElapsed = false;

$(window).on('load', function() {
    pageLoaded = true;
    if (timeoutElapsed) {
        load_func();
    }
});

setTimeout(function() {
    timeoutElapsed = true;
    if (pageLoaded) {
        load_func();
    }
}, 2000);
```

This way, if the page loads before 2 seconds, it will wait the timeout to call the function.

Otherwise, if the page loads after 2 seconds, it will call it whenever that `load` event happened.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Good explaining and works like a charm :3

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
 $(window).on('load', function() {
        setTimeout( function(){
           $('.preloader').fadeOut('slow'); 
        }, 2000 )
    });
```

Comment: If a page takes 3 seconds to load (images, css, etc), then this script will run the script 
after 5 seconds total, not the expected 3 seconds.